# Heroku app crashed Error H10.. cannot resolve, please help

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

The error message:

```
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:46
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `initialize'
2011-06-09T18:39:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-06-09T18:39:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-06-09T11:45:07-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation started
2011-06-09T18:45:25+00:00 heroku[api]: Deploy 8a7b7bd by abhijitbendale@gmail.com
2011-06-09T18:45:25+00:00 heroku[api]: Release v222 created by abhijitbendale@gmail.com
2011-06-09T18:45:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-06-09T18:45:25+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-06-09T11:45:26-07:00 heroku[slugc]: Slug compilation finished
2011-06-09T18:45:34+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 42545 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-06-09T18:45:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Starting the New Relic Agent.
2011-06-09T18:45:36+00:00 app[web.1]: Installed New Relic Browser Monitoring middleware
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:436:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:485:in `parse'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:46:in `formatted_api_key'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:42:in `api_key'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:56:in `send'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:56:in `[]'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sender.rb:7:in `initialize'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sender.rb:6:in `each'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sender.rb:6:in `initialize'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sms.rb:12:in `new'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sms.rb:12:in `configure'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environments/production.rb:18
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `run_load_hooks'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:46
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-06-09T18:45:37+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-06-09T18:45:38+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2011-06-09T18:46:38+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET visionblocks.org/ dyno= queue= wait= service= bytes=
2011-06-09T18:46:39+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET visionblocks.org/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= bytes=
2011-06-09T11:46:39-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 18.111.60.189 | 796 | http | 503
2011-06-09T18:46:40+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET visionblocks.org/ dyno= queue= wait= service= bytes=
2011-06-09T18:46:40+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET visionblocks.org/favicon.ico dyno=none queue=0 wait=0ms service=0ms bytes=0
2011-06-09T11:46:40-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 18.111.60.189 | 795 | http | 503
2011-06-09T18:46:41+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET visionblocks.org/ dyno= queue= wait= service= bytes=
2011-06-09T18:46:41+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App crashed) -> GET visionblocks.org/favicon.ico dyno= queue= wait= service= bytes=
2011-06-09T11:46:41-07:00 heroku[nginx]: GET / HTTP/1.1 | 18.111.60.189 | 795 | http | 503
2011-06-09T18:50:24+00:00 heroku[deployhooks]: Notified New Relic about the deploy
2011-06-09T18:51:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to created
2011-06-09T18:51:11+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from created to starting
2011-06-09T18:51:42+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command: `thin -p 37067 -e production -R /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru start`
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]: /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:436:in `split': bad URI(is not URI?):  (URI::InvalidURIError)
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/1.8/uri/common.rb:485:in `parse'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:46:in `formatted_api_key'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:42:in `api_key'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:56:in `send'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/configuration.rb:56:in `[]'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sender.rb:7:in `initialize'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sender.rb:6:in `each'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sender.rb:6:in `initialize'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sms.rb:12:in `new'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/moonshado-sms-1.1.0/lib/moonshado/sms.rb:12:in `configure'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environments/production.rb:18
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `call'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:34:in `execute_hook'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:43:in `run_load_hooks'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `each'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/activesupport-3.0.0/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:42:in `run_load_hooks'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:46
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `instance_exec'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in `run'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in `run_initializers'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `each'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in `run_initializers'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:134:in `initialize!'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `send'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/railties-3.0.0/lib/rails/application.rb:77:in `method_missing'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/config/environment.rb:5
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /usr/ruby1.8.7/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from config.ru:3
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /home/heroku_rack/heroku.ru:23
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 app[web.1]:   from /app/.bundle/gems/ruby/1.8/gems/rack-1.2.1/lib/rack/builder.rb:46:in `instance_eval'
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
2011-06-09T18:51:45+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
```

Comment: can we see production.rb, line 18 please.

Comment: Thanks John. That was a good lead. I checked my production.rb (~/config/environments/production.rb) and in that file I had some lines related to an external library (moonshado-sms) (which i didn't need and it was obsolete ).. I commented the code related to it and also in my Gemfile, updated the Gemfile.lock (gem bundle update) and then pushed the app to heroku and my application started working again... thanks for the lead... this error was giving me lot of trouble..!!! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

can we see production.rb, line 18 please.

EDIT: I'll add it as an answer so you can flag it as the answer :)