# Heroku "App Crashed" log error

Tags: python, django, heroku

I'm coming back to a Django project after some time away from it.  I'm trying to open my project on Heroku so I can make sure things are working while I am deploying, but for some reason I can't get the app to open.

The site looks like this:

[image]

And I get the following error in the logs:

> 2016-01-12T08:27:56.058699+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=infinite-sands-4858.herokuapp.com request_id=ee6b2dfc-b047-40eb-82e5-0ab549d3c8e9 fwd="172.110.63.49" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=

I've tried researching this using various pieces of the error, but Google is giving me nothing. (Like actually zero results.)  The error isn't exactly giving me much to go on either.  I also hadn't changed anything coming back into this project, and it was working before perfectly fine, so I have no idea what this could possibly be caused by.

Comment: Might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6298002/heroku-app-crashed-error-h10-cannot-resolve-please-help

Comment: restart the app and observe the logs, that would show a stack trace if it's crashed on boot.